# Calculating date_range over GroupBy object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a massive dataframe with four columns, two of which are 'date' (in `datetime` format) and 'page' (a location saved as a `string`). I have grouped the dataframe by 'page' and called it `pagegroup`, and want to know the range of time over which each page is accessed (e.g. the first access was on 1-1-13, the last on 1-5-13, so the max-min is 5 days).

I know in pandas I can use `date_range` to compare two datetimes, but trying something like:

```
pagegroup['date'].agg(np.date_range)
```

returns

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'date_range'
```

while trying the simple (non date-specific) numpy function `ptp` gives me an integer answer:

```
daterange = pagegroup['date'].agg([np.ptp])
daterange.head()

                           ptp
page                          
%2F                          0
/            13325984000000000
/-509606456    297697000000000
/-511484155                  0
/-511616154                  0
```

Can anyone think of a way to calculate the range of dates and have it return in a recognizable date format?

Thank you

Comment: [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality) is a pandas function (so it's `pd.date_range` not `np`), but it doesn't compare two datetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have indexed by datetime can use groupby apply:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4]],
                            columns=list('ab'),
                            index=pd.date_range('2013', freq='H', periods=3)



In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
                     a  b
2013-08-22 00:00:00  1  2
2013-08-22 01:00:00  1  3
2013-08-22 02:00:00  2  4

In [13]: g = df.groupby('a')

In [14]: g.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1].name - x.iloc[0].name)
Out[14]: 
a
1   01:00:00
2   00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

*Here `iloc[-1]` grabs the last row in the group and `iloc[0]` gets the first. The name attribute is the index of the row.*

@Elyase points out that this only works if the original DatetimeIndex was in order, if not you can use max/min (which actually reads better, but may be less efficient):

```
In [15]: g.apply(lambda x: x.index.max() - x.index.min())
Out[15]: 
a
1   01:00:00
2   00:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Note: to get the timedelta between two Timestamps we have just subtracted (`-`).

If date is a column rather than an index, then use the column name:

```
g.apply(lambda x: x['date'].iloc[-1] - x['date'].iloc[0])
g.apply(lambda x: x['date'].max() - x['date'].min())
```

Comment: may be you need to sort the groups, I think he wants the earliest and the latest date in each group.

Comment: @elyase tbh not 100% sure what desired result is. Oh, I think I see what you're suggesting, the above assumes that the the DatetimeIndex is ordered. Good point. Will update with max and min.